# How do I get a radio element in a popover?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on a dashbord site where data from the database is displayed in a table. One of the columns contains text from the database, if you click on that text you will get a popover.

The thing I want within this popover is the option to change the text with a radio element. The problem im having now is that whenever I am putting in html in the popover content, it shows the full HTML

HTML/PHP code:

```
$radio = '<div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
          Default radio
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
          Second default radio
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check disabled">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
          Disabled radio
        </label>
      </div>';
....

$output .= .....
<td><a tabindex='0' class='pointer' data-toggle='popover' data-trigger='' title='Dismissible popoverf' data-content='".$radio."'>".$status."</a></td>
...;
```

expected output: radio in popover-content
actual output: html code in popover-content

I hope i've provided enough information, if not please let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: can I see the popup code where you put the data-content?

Comment: or initialize the popover I mean! 

it should be something like that:

$('#example').popover()

Comment: What library are you using for the popover? Injecting HTML in a `data-` attribute seems like a bad practice. If you can, create a function which generates the HTML client side and outputs it where it should be. Be sure to include your **relevant** JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho it is a bad idea to inject the HTML like that, I am going to show you how to fix it, But please note that it is still a bad idea.

Change this part

```
<td><a tabindex='0' class='pointer' data-toggle='popover' data-trigger='' title='Dismissible popoverf' data-content='".$radio."'>".$status."</a></td>
```

to this:

```
<td><a tabindex='0' class='pointer' data-toggle='popover' data-trigger='' title='Dismissible popoverf' data-html="true" data-content='".$radio."'>".$status."</a></td>
```

Source:

[Bootstrap Popovers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/)

Comment: Ty for your help, do you have a suggestion to add the html in a better way?

Comment: I would recommend doing what Emiel Suggested, or you could have for example, an external php file which has the code you want, and when someone clicks on the popover, you load it using ajax